# Filter S3 list-objects results to find a key matching a pattern

Tags: amazon-s3, pattern-matching, aws-cli, jmespath

I would like to use the AWS CLI to query the contents of a bucket and see if a particular file exists, but the bucket contains thousands of files.  How can I filter the results to only show key names that match a pattern?  For example:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket myBucketName --query "Contents[?Key==*mySearchPattern*]"
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The `--query` argument uses JMESPath expressions.  [JMESPath has an internal function `contains`](http://jmespath.readthedocs.org/en/latest/specification.html#contains) that allows you to search for a string pattern.

This should give the desired results:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket myBucketName --query "Contents[?contains(Key, `mySearchPattern`)]"
```

(With Linux I needed to use single quotes `'` rather than back ticks `` ` `` around `mySearchPattern`.)

If you want to search for keys *starting* with certain characters, you can also use the `--prefix` argument:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket myBucketName --prefix "myPrefixToSearchFor"
```

Comment: On Linux using single quotes didn't work. But escaping the backticks worked. (Eg. \\`mySearchPattern\\` )

Comment: Also, if mySearchPattern is a pure number (eg. `20150101` ) then the CLI complains it should be a string and not an integer. Even through you did quote it. Didn't find a solution except include a non-digit in the searchPattern (eg. `20150101/` ) then it doesn't complain.

Comment: Thanks for the single quotes comment ! I was wondering wtf was going on ,,,,

Comment: `--prefix` did the trick for me which worked well with real "S3 prefixes" combined with a prefix for an object name, for example `--prefix myS3Prefix/myFileNamePrefix`. Where the full object key is `myS3Prefix/myFileNamePrefix_blahblah`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried on Ubuntu 14, awscli 1.2

```
--query "Contents[?contains(Key,'stati')].Key" 
--query "Contents[?contains(Key,\'stati\')].Key" 
--query "Contents[?contains(Key,`stati`)].Key"
```

Illegal token value `'?contains(Key,'stati')].Key'`

After upgraded the aws version to 1.16 , worked with

```
--query "Contents[?contains(Key,'stati')].Key"
```