# Query and limit S3 bucket for files ending in .css

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to list all of the files in an AWS S3 bucket that end in .css.

I saw this question: [Filter S3 list-objects results to find a key matching a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274996/filter-s3-list-objects-results-to-find-a-key-matching-a-pattern) and from reading it, I tried this:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket mybucket --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'css')]"
```

That returned every file inside a /css folder as well as files with 'css' anywhere in the name. I want the equivalent of find "*.css". Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [ends_with](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#ends-with) function.

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket mybucket --query "Contents[?ends_with(Key, 'css')]"
```