# Search specific file in AWS S3 bucket using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, boto3, botocore

I have AWS S3 access and the bucket has nearly 300 files inside the bucket. I need to download single file from this bucket by pattern matching or search because i do not know the exact filename (Say files ends with .csv format).
Here is my sample code which shows all files inside the bucket

```
def s3connection(credentialsdict):
    """
    :param access_key: Access key for AWS to establish S3 connection
    :param secret_key: Secret key for AWS to establish S3 connection
    :param file_name: file name of the billing file(csv file)
    :param bucket_name: Name of the bucket which consists of billing files
    :return: status, billing_bucket, billing_key
    """
    os.environ['S3_USE_SIGV4'] = 'True'
    conn = S3Connection(credentialsdict["access_key"], credentialsdict["secret_key"], host='s3.amazonaws.com')
    billing_bucket = conn.get_bucket(credentialsdict["bucket_name"], validate=False)
    try:
        billing_bucket.get_location()
    except S3ResponseError as e:
        if e.status == 400 and e.error_code == 'AuthorizationHeaderMalformed':
            conn.auth_region_name = ET.fromstring(e.body).find('./Region').text
    billing_bucket = conn.get_bucket(credentialsdict["bucket_name"])
    print billing_bucket

    if not billing_bucket:
        raise Exception("Please Enter valid bucket name. Bucket %s does not exist"
                        % credentialsdict.get("bucket_name"))
    for key in billing_bucket.list():
        print key.name
    del os.environ['S3_USE_SIGV4']
```

Can I pass search string to retrieve the exact matched filenames?

Answer (score 5):

You can use JMESPath expressions to search and filter down S3 files. To do that you need to get s3 paginator over `list_objects_v2`.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket="your_bucket_name")
```

Now that you have iterator you can use JMESPath search.
Most useful is [contains](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#contains) - to do `%like%` query

```
objects = page_iterator.search("Contents[?contains(Key, `partial-file-name`)][]")
```

But in your case (to find all files ending `.csv` it's better to use [ends_with](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#ends-with) - to do `*.csv` query

```
objects = page_iterator.search("Contents[?ends_with(Key, `.csv`)][]")
```

Then you can get object keys with

```
for item in objects:
    print(item['Key'])
```

This answer is based on https://blog.jeffbryner.com/2020/04/21/jupyter-pandas-analysis.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/27274997/4587704

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this because there is no native support for `regex` in S3. You have to get the entire list and apply the search/regex at the client side. The only filtering option available in `list_objects` is by `prefix`.

[list_objects](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects)

> Prefix (string) -- Limits the response to keys that begin with the
>   specified prefix.

One option is to use the Python module `re` and apply it to the list of objects.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(<file_pattern_you_are_looking_for>)
for key in billing_bucket.list():
    if pattern.match(key.name):
        print key.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the simple if condition like,

```
prefix_objs = buck.objects.filter(Prefix="your_bucket_path")

for obj in prefix_objs:
    key = obj.key
    if key.endswith(".csv"):
        body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
        print(obj.key)
```