# How To Filter, Pattern-Match Files on Retrieval from AWS S3 using .NET AWS SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When using the `ListObjects` request (.NET AWS SDK), is there a way to only list files where the key matches a given pattern? Or, more broadly, is there a way to query files from `S3` based on their key using any request type from the .NET AWS SDK?

I'm aware of the [`--query` param, available on AWS CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274996/filter-s3-list-objects-results-to-find-a-key-matching-a-pattern), but I'm not able to find an equivalent method on .NET.

I'm looking for a way to run the query **server-side** so that `ListObjects` returns a pattern-matching set of keys. I'd like to avoid retrieving all files `and then` filter them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS CLI uses [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/) for query expressions. There is a .NET port called [JmesPath.NET](https://github.com/jdevillard/JmesPath.Net) that is compatible with the same API and is well-maintained. You could use the SDK to retrieve the result set, and then filter it with JmesPath.NET expressions. It's available as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JmesPath.Net/) too.

The `--query` param on the CLI filters the result set on output, similar to what would happen with JmesPath.NET. It doesn't affect what the API call returns. The only request parameters available to reduce the result set are `prefix` and `delimiter`, which group things logically like a folder structure does in a file storage engine. Unless your use case can be handled by those parameters, you're stuck with filtering on the output side.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a way to run the query **server-side** so that `ListObjects` returns a pattern-matching set of keys. I'd like to avoid retrieving all files _and then_ filter them.

Comment: The --query param on the CLI filters the result set on output, similar to what would happen with JmesPath.NET. It doesn't affect what the API call returns. The only request parameters available to reduce the result set are prefix and delimiter, which essentially help you group things logically like a folder structure does in a file storage engine. Unless your use case can be handled by those parameters, you're stuck with filtering on the output side.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll refactor things to work post-retrieval then.  Could you update your answer to include that last bit?